# How to show different educational institutions' login options in an app?

Tags: mobile-application, login, app, education, signup

I'm working on a mobile application where users, apart from being able to login and sign up with accounts made directly on the app, have the ability to login directly with their educational institutions' credentials. There are around 50 different institutions. What's the best way to display/choose your institution and login using those credentials in addition to being able to signup/login regularly?

Comment: Can you show some work that illustrates how you tried to solve this problem? To me it sounds as if a simple searchable combobox would solve it.

Comment: I haven't yet done it on the application, but on the website here https://feedbackbox.dk/ you can find how it looks like currently

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this mockup I did quickly. Hope this helps. It has instructions written on it. [image: Mockup]

Make sure to offer your users a search functionality so that they can see which institute's credentials are accepted for ease of use with the login. Can use auto suggest. Please excuse my typos.